# Set different versionCode for different flavors dimension combination [Kotlin DSL]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my app I have 2 dimensions "app" and "server" and in that I have 4 flavors. Now I want to have different versionCode for different flavor combination.

For Example:-

- For *ApponeLive* I want to have versionCode 1.
- For *ApponeStaging* I want to have versionCode 2.

*build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
flavorDimensions.add("app")
flavorDimensions.add("server")

productFlavors {
    create("Appone") {
        val appName = "App One"
        applicationId = "com.app.one"
        dimension = "app"
        resValue("string", "appName", appName)
        manifestPlaceholders["launcherName"] = appName
    }

    create("Apptwo") {
        val appName = "App Two"
        applicationId = "com.app.two"
        dimension = "app"
        resValue("string", "appName", appName)
        manifestPlaceholders["launcherName"] = appName
    }

    create("live") {
        dimension = "server"
        manifestPlaceholders["appNameSuffix"] = ""
    }

    create("staging") {
        dimension = "server"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".staging"
        versionNameSuffix = "-staging"
        manifestPlaceholders["appNameSuffix"] = " Staging"
    }
}
```

---

I have tried to set version code using *"applicationVariants.configureEach { }"* but versionCode is val which means it cannot be reassigned.

According to *"ProductFlavor.kt"*

> The version code associated with this flavor or null if none have been
> set. This is only the value set on this product flavor, not
> necessarily the actual version code used.

```kotlin
applicationVariants.configureEach {

        val app = productFlavors[0].name
        val server = productFlavors[1].name

        if (app == "Appone" && server == "live"){
            mergedFlavor.versionCode = 1
        }else if (app == "Appone" && server == "staging"){
            mergedFlavor.versionCode = 2
        }else {
            //Do something..
        }
    }
```

---

I even tried by casting *"MergedFlavor"* but it resulted in failed the gradle task and showed this which I assume is for Groovy.

```kotlin
applicationVariants.configureEach {

        val app = productFlavors[0].name
        val server = productFlavors[1].name

        if (app == "Appone" && server == "live"){
            (mergedFlavor as MergedFlavor).versionCode = 1
        }else if (app == "Appone" && server == "staging"){
            (mergedFlavor as MergedFlavor).versionCode = 2
        }else {
            //Do something..
        }
    }
```

### *Gradle Error*

> versionCode cannot be set on a mergedFlavor directly.
> versionCodeOverride can instead be set for variant outputs using the
> following syntax:
>
> ```kotlin
> android {
>     applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>         variant.outputs.each { output ->
>             output.versionCodeOverride = 1
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

Now I'm out of ideas, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you also need a different version code if the dimension is different ? You can set versionCode directly when declaring flavors [versionCode is a var](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationBaseFlavor#versionCode()). 
`productFlavors { create("Appone") { versionCode = 123 } }`

Comment: @LionelBriand I want different versions code for different flavours combinations. I'm aware that I can set the version code directly in product flavours but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: From the gradle error you put. I've found `applicationVariants.configureEach { outputs.configureEach { (this as com.android.build.gradle.api.ApkVariantOutput).versionCodeOverride = 123 } }`

Comment: @LionelBriand It worked but it is deprecated, do you know any alternative to it ?

Comment: No, I do not know any other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I came up with this and It worked for me but I'm not sure if it is an optimal solution.

Let me know if any optimisation can be done.

```kotlin
android {
    androidComponents.onVariants {
        val app = it.productFlavors[0].second
        val server = it.productFlavors[1].second
        val output = it.outputs.firstOrNull() ?: return@onVariants


        if (app == "Appone" && server == "live"){
            output.versionCode.set(1)
        }else if (app == "Appone" && server == "staging"){
            output.versionCode.set(2)
        }else {
            //Add your logic
        }
    
    } 
}
```

### Explanaton

```kotlin
fun onVariants(
        selector: VariantSelector = selector().all(),
        callback: (VariantT) -> Unit
)
```

Code executing in the callback also has access to the VariantT information which is used to configure org.gradle.api.Task inputs (for example, the buildConfigFields). Such information represented as org.gradle.api.provider.Property can still be modified ensuring that all org.gradle.api.Tasks created by the Android Gradle Plugin use the updated value.